# Can Anyone Tell me How to get system date in Jtextfield?

Tags: java

```
t2=new JTextField(5);
this.add(t2);
t2.setBounds(450,50,100,20);
```

> This is my query !! Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Use a JFormattedTextField or SimpleDateFormat (or DateFomat) to format the Date value to String...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Date date = new Date();//you could use Calander and formatter if you need date in particular format.
t2.setText(date.toString());
```